# Cannot view or delete a table in BigQuery when it is named/saved as "test"

Tags: google-bigquery

I have created a query destination table that resulted in this message even though  I saved the results of a query, and did not import data using the automatic schema detection feature.

I named the table "*test*".

> "The schema for this table was automatically detected. If the schema
>   was not correctly detected, you can re-run the load job with an
>   adjusted schema. Dismiss."

[image: BigQuery Interface]

The table is displayed in the dataset, but when I try to access it the error message displays and there is no data present:

> Unable to find table: [removed]:[removed].test Dismiss

Also, when I try to delete it via the web UI nothing happens, and the network request in the browser returns a `404`.

Why can I not view or delete this table?

Comment: "The schema for this table..." -- it's not an error. If you are satisfied with the auto-detected schema, then you can just ignore this message.

Regarding on the deletion issue -- if the table name happens to be "test", then we are aware of the issue and the fix is on the way.

Comment: I can reproduce this. This is clearly a bug in BigQuery as @xuejian has already confirmed. I've raised an official issue because I could not find existing one: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36144551

Comment: Same goes for table names that contain `association`